# java program to read text file and output with out duplicate? loop to skip duplicate line

Tags: java, jgrasp

I was suppose to read text file and display original file and output file without any duplicate line.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class questionOne {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException  {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("text.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);


        System.out.println("ORIGINAL FILE: input.txt contains the values   ");


        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        scanner.close();

        System.out.println("OUTPUT FILE: output.txt contains the values");

        // String a = 

    }   
}
```

Comment: In order to help you get an answer, it would be better if you could actually phrase this as a question. What is it specifically you would like help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Set` structure to do this. Instead of displaying what you have read, store it, and print the set.

Use this method:

```
Set<String> uniqueLines = new TreeSet<>();
//in a loop
uniqueLines.add(scanner.nextLine();
// display the set
```

Since this is a homework question, I won't give the whole answer. Good luck with your code :)